# vaadin wth opening new window on clcik of menu command

Tags: menu, vaadin

I m using menu items which are given in vaadin menu demo example ,on click of each menu item i m showing notification message, but my requrement is i have to open new class on click of submenu item some one give me demo example in vaadin how open new window on click of menu item

Answer (score 3):

Here's a short example showing how I open another top-level window in Vaadin. You have to supply a unique name for the window (the setName call). Then you call Vaadin to find the URL for the newly created window, and then open it. In this case "window" is a variable that holds my primary application window.

```java
reportWindow = injector.getInstance(GeneralReportWindow.class);
reportWindow.setName("report_overview");
reportWindow.setGenerator(injector.getInstance(OverviewGenerator.class));

addWindow(reportWindow);

try {
    URI reportURI = reportWindow.getURL().toURI();
    URL windowURL = new URI(reportURI.getScheme(), 
        reportURI.getUserInfo(), reportURI.getHost(), 
        reportURI.getPort(), reportURI.getPath(), "report=overview", null).toURL();
    window.open(new ExternalResource(windowURL, "_new"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.warn("Unable to create report window", e);
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for giving me sample code please can you give me some more details of code i m finding difficult in implementing ,if you provide me example it is great help full for me